# "Get this version" Greyed out in Project's View History

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, tfs

After getting a migration error, (unable to create a manifest resource name for Migrations) I connected to TFS, went to the project's view history and was going to retrieve an earlier version. However, the option was greyed out.  People online suggested rebooting, getting rid of the local project file and re-downloading it from TFS, and asking the team if anyone deleted a file.  After doing all these, nothing seems to have helped.  I also ran the update-database command in Package manager console, which resulted in a build failure error.  Does anyone know what commonly causes this or what may be going on?